# Setting application level margin property

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, margins

We are trying to follow [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511279.aspx#sizingspacing) guidelines.
For this I want to set application level style or properties to set the margins between controls.

I am not able to set the margins through style as it ask me for target object and there might be the cases when I don't want to follow the above.

I am able to set the margin by making some getter properties in App.xaml.cs

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Gets the margin to be set all around the dialog
    /// </summary>
    public Thickness MarginsAllAroundDialog
    {
      get
      {
        // returns default margin
        return new Thickness(7);
      }
    }
```

and setting the margin to the dialog as:

```
<Window x:Class="XXX.Views.MainWindow"
        x:Name="mainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Margin="{Binding Path=MarginsAllAroundDialog, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"
        Height="350" 
        Width="525"
        WindowState="Maximized">
```

Is this the correct way or we achieve the same by simpler means.

Comment: "I am not able to set the margins through style as it ask me for target object and there might be the cases when I don't want to follow the above" There's nothing stopping you from overriding it in those cases. If you explicitly specify a Margin on a control, that will override the style.

Comment: Thanks Joe was not aware of that :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your approach is good enough, but consider declaring margins in XAML.

You can define margins as resources in your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <Thickness x:Key="MarginsAllAroundDialog" Bottom="7" Left="7" Right="7" Top="7" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And reference these resources instead of using binding:

```
<Window x:Class="XXX.Views.MainWindow"
        Margin="{StaticResource MarginsAllAroundDialog}">
```

Comment: This is an much cleaner approach I was looking for.

I tried to do the same using 
<Style>
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="7,7,7,7" />
</Style>
But it wont compile :-(


I tried

Comment: If you want it to apply to everything, you need to specify `<Style TargetType="SomeType">`, so it knows which `Margin` property you mean. Repeat the whole `<Style>` declaration for each element type you want to apply margins to.